# How to specify "one at a time" in UML?

Tags: class, time, constraints, uml, class-diagram

I'm making a class diagram with a `Classroom` and a `Course` class.

How can I indicate that a `Classroom` can only have one `Course` in it at a time?  I know I can use multiplicities to specify that a classroom can have exactly one course, but that doesn't exactly specify that there can be other courses than that one course at different times.

Answer (score 4):

### First solution and temporal issues

[Bruno's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64192130/3723423) with a `0..1` multiplicity satisfies your explicit requirement: a `Classroom` can then indeed hold at most one `Course` at any given time. But it has as consequence that at this given time:

- the `Classroom` doesn't know any other `Course` that has or will taken place in it.
- Any other `Course` that will take place in this `Classroom` in future does not know at this moment where it will take place.

So if you're in the business of time-table and resource scheduling,  this solution will not fulfil the other implicit needs that you didn't mention so far.

### Where is the time in your design?

UML provides only limited built-in temporal semantics. You need to add time explicitly in your model. What is missing here is therefore the time slots:

- the time slot is not necessarily bound to the `Course`;  An "*Initiation to C++*" course may need several lessons, that could take place in several rooms at different times.
- the time slot is obviously not either bound to the `Classroom`.

#### An intuitive solution

A `TimeSlot` can be viewed as related to the association of a `Course` and to a `Classroom`. For every course taking place in a room, you'll have to manage the start and end time. This is very natural to model as an association class:

[image]

This does not address your "unicity" requirement, but it facilitates its expression with a constraint expressed in natural languate: `{Timeslots for a same Classroom cannot overlap}`.  You may also express it more formally in OCL.

#### An alternative approach

You may also analyse the time problem differently, and consider the `Classroom` as a service offer, composed of `RoomSlots` that correspond to time intervals. Each `RoomSlot` would then associated to `0..1` course as Bruno suggested:

[image]

This approach makes the management of the time slots more obvious and independent:

- you may use fixed time slots of 1 hour, you may allow dynamic time slots by adding, splitting and merging time slots of a same room as needed, always enforcing absence of overlaps.
- the management of the room availability can be analysed and implemented independently of the room usage
- Unassociated `RoomSlots` explicitly shows available rooms (offer) at a given time, and unassigned `Courses` shows the needs (demand).

Comment: When I wrote my answer I of course thought to extend it to speak about the usage schedule, but I also thought you will probably do ;-) As usual a as clear as complete answer, congratulation

Comment: @Bruno Thank you! This kind of exchange shows the benefits of modelling: your answer helped to identify missing requirements, and at my 2nd alternative, I realized that it would not prevent the same course to take place twice at the same time in different rooms, which raises further questions regarding the multiplicity on the opposite side of the Course (e.g. is it one single content held by multiple teachers each in one time slot? is it content split over a multiple set of lessons/hours by a single teacher? does the decomposition in time slots match the decomposition of the content? etc.)

Comment: @Chistophe I think a more natural solution is to model *class meetings* (similar to your *time slots*) as components of *courses* and associate exactly one *class room* with a *class meeting* adding a constraint (similar to your *time slot* constraint) that *class meetings* in the same room must not overlap.

Comment: @GerdWagner Thanks for the suggestion.  Indeed, I was also thinking of dividing a course into something that could be assigned to one room in a given time. The name that came to my mind was "lesson", but this would have been ambiguous, since "lesson" is often a content-based decomposition. I like the idea of "class meeting". I hope nevertheless that OP has now sufficient elements to develop the model as suit the real requirements, since the needs expressed in the question are rather limited.

Answer (score 2):

The multiplicity is the right way to do, and in your case it is `0..1` because a classroom can be unused => no associated course. A course can be made in different classrooms or even none if outside so I use `*`.

[image]

> that doesn't exactly specify that there can be other courses than that one course at different times

I disagree, the association `Classroom --- Course` does not specify the associated course (and classroom(s)) cannot change, so without additional constraint or setting it *readOnly* it can change